# I keep getting this image seemingly randomly and frequently

Tags: boot

[image]

I am new to Ubuntu and installed it about 8 weeks ago. I have no other OS installed. At random this will appear instead of a boot. I have found no reliable way to fix this. I have tried leaving the usb in and booting other versions of the OS. Nothing works. Do any of you know what is going on?